# Xamarin Forms Picker Binding breaks when Itemssource changes

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a problem with Binding Data to a Picker in Xamarin Forms and hpe somebody can help me. I have a ContentPage which holds a picker. The Itemssource for that Picker is queried async from a web service. Also, the view (or rather, the ViewModel) is passed a seleted item. For whatever reason, setting the itemssource breaks the binding of the SelectedItem property.

Here is my ViewModel -

```
public class ExerciseViewModel:BaseViewModel
    {
        private ApiServices apiService = new ApiServices();
        private Exercise exercise;
        public Exercise Exercise
        {
            get => exercise;
            set
            {
                exercise = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private List<ExerciseCategory> exerciseCategories = new List<ExerciseCategory>();
        public List<ExerciseCategory> ExerciseCategories
        {
            get => exerciseCategories;
            set
            {
                exerciseCategories = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ExerciseViewModel()
        {
            GetCategoriesCommand.Execute(null);
            Exercise = new Exercise() { Name = "Neue Übung", Category = ExerciseCategories.FirstOrDefault() };
        }

        public ExerciseViewModel(Exercise ex)
        {
            Exercise = ex;
            GetCategoriesCommand.Execute(null);
        }

        public ICommand GetCategoriesCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    ExerciseCategories = await apiService.GetExerciseCategories();
                });
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddExerciseCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    Exercise.Id = await apiService.AddExercise(Exercise);
                });
            }
        }


    }
```

This is the Entity in question - the necessary operators are overloaded, INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in the BaseClass -

```
public class ExerciseCategory:BaseClass
    {
        private string name;
        private int id;

        [Key]
        public int Id
        {
            get => id;
            set
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var other = (obj as ExerciseCategory);
            if (other is null)
                return false;
            return this == other;
        }
        public static bool operator !=(ExerciseCategory e1, ExerciseCategory e2)
        {
            return !(e1 == e2);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(ExerciseCategory e1, ExerciseCategory e2)
        {
            if (e1.Id == e2.Id)
                if (e1.Name == e2.Name)
                    return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the page's CodeBehind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class NewExercisePage : ContentPage
    {
        public NewExercisePage(ExerciseViewModel viewModel, bool controlsLocked = false)
        {
            try
            {
                this.BindingContext = viewModel;
                InitializeComponent();


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateWebView(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri uriResult;
            bool result = Uri.TryCreate(e.NewTextValue, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult)
                && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
            if (result)
                exerciseVideoViewer.Source = e.NewTextValue;
        }
    }
```

Finally, here is the XAML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="PerformanceTM.Views.NewExercisePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <WebView x:Name="exerciseVideoViewer" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200"></WebView>
            <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid">
                <Label Text="Kategorie" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Picker x:Name="CategoryPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding ExerciseCategories}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding Exercise.Category}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Label Text="Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Exercise.Name}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <Label Text="Video URL" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Exercise.VideoUrl}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" TextChanged="UpdateWebView"/>
                    <Label Text="Beschreibung" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3"/>
                    <Editor Text="{Binding Exercise.Description}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4"/>
                </Grid>
            <Button Text="Speichern" Command="{Binding AddExerciseCommand}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Exercise.Category.Name}"/>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

When I select an ExerciseCategory from the CategoryPicker, Binding works. However, the ExerciseCategory that is prvided to the ViewModel via the "ex" parameter does not result in the proper Category being selected in the Picker.

Since the Categories are not (necessarily) present by the time I call InitializeComponent, I suspect this disconnection between the Exercise.Category and the Picker.SelectedItem comes from that late binding. Still, I cannot really figure out how to fix that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: SelectedItem must be a reference to one of the elements of ItemsSource.  You are passing in an Exercise (and it's related category) to the VM's constructor, then loading the category list from the API, creating two different instances of the selected category.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought. it's still strange, though, as I have overloaded the Equals and == operators, so I hoped that'd take care of that. Loading all data well in advance necessitates a clever update strategy, as users can add categories at any time...